# What is tellg() in file handling in c++ and how does it work?

Tags: c++, file-handling

I tried to access the next characters to be read from the file using `tellg()` and returns the position correctly if the file has one line of text.. But when the file has more than one line it gives me some abnormal values.. I am attaching my code and the output i got below..

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
       char temp;
       ifstream ifile("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\hello.txt");
       ifile>>noskipws;
       while(ifile>>temp)
       {
           cout<<temp<<" "<<ifile.tellg()<<endl;
       }
   }

   output:
      H 3
      e 4
      l 5
      l 6
      o 7

        8
      W 9
      o 10
      r 11
      l 12
      d 13
      . 14
      . 15

        16
      ! 17
      ! 18
      ! 19

    File : Hello.txt contains 3 lines as given below..

           Hello
           World
           !!!
```

Don't understand why it starts with `3` in the print statement which should instead start from `1`.. when there are `2` lines it starts printing from `2`.. 
can anyone explain me..?

Comment: Are you sure that your file doesn't have any newline or whitespace characters before "Hello World  !!!"?? Since you are using `noskipws` so it might be possible that there are some whitespace characters present at start of your file.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this was on Windows and the file has a BOM marker

Comment: @sehe you should make this a response (looking at the file path it is Windows)

Comment: @PravarJawalekar ya it has newlines and spaces but not before `hello`..  but my question y does it start with `3` instead of `1`..

Comment: @sehe ya it is with windows.. y is this happening..?

Comment: You can use tellg to get a value to use with seekg. That's all you can use it for. It could be a random hash cookie and it would still be a valid return value from tellg. Don't try to understand it.

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/fpos

Comment: And http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/streamoff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of fact tellg() is not to return the offset of a byte in a stream, but a pos_type descriptor which is reusable by seekg(). It will match the byte offset if the file is binary, but it is not guaranteed in a text stream. (In a *ix it will match too, but in Windows there is no direct assignment.)

Open the file in binary mode, because seekg() is used with an offset. If the modification of the file happens between two runs of your program, you'll need to store positionEof in a file.

Note: In binary mode you could actually store positionEof in an integer, but I prefer using the explicite type as long as it is possible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    streampos positionEof;

    // Record original eof position.
    ifstream instream("C:\\Users\\istvan\\Desktop\\hello.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (instream.is_open()) {
        instream.seekg(0, ios::end);
        positionEof = instream.tellg();     // store the end-of-file position
        instream.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "Record eof position: file open error" << endl;

    // Append something to the file to simulate the modification.
    ofstream outstream("C:\\Users\\istvan\\Desktop\\hello.txt", ios::app);
    if (outstream.is_open()) {
        cout << "write" << endl;
        outstream << "appended text";
        outstream.close();
    }

    // Check what was appended.
    instream.open("C:\\Users\\istvan\\Desktop\\hello.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (instream.is_open()) {
        instream.seekg(positionEof);    // Set the read position to the previous eof
        char c;
        while ( instream.get(c))
            cout << c;

        instream.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "Check modification: file open error!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how to overcome this drawback in windows.?

Comment: I shouldn't call it a Windows drawback, it is just the way it works. Just because it happens to match in Unix, its purpose is not to count characters in the input stream. Could you explain the actual problem you need to solve please?

Comment: when traverse through the document by single character at a time and find the new characters appended to the file i have no other option to use the combination of `tellg` with `seekg`. Due to the way it is working i am not able to get the content appended to file as a whole.. Do i Have other options.? @IFaz

Comment: Sorry, I still cannot see the task. Is it not possible to read the whole document into memory and process it there?

Comment: My task is to find the appended data in a file.. If initially my content is "Hello" and i am appending the text "world".. I want to display the appended text "World".. Can u understand my specification.?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand it. See example in my answer.

Comment: Ya its right..it is working correctly.. But i could not understand y didnt work for text document..

Comment: It is just the way things defined. This overloaded seekg(offset, direction) function requires binary file to open. Once seekg needs a position in binary mode, tellg() needs to provide it so. Glad you can proceed after all.